# Bundle angular 2 project with lazy loaded module using gulp

Tags: angular, gulp, bundle, systemjs, lazy-loading

I have an app which serves components with lazy loading and it works fine on development environment but it gives an error after I bundle it for production mentioned below.

```
ErrorHandler : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: System.import is not a function
TypeError: System.import is not a function
    at a.loadAndCompile (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:37406)
    at a.load (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:37397)
    at a.loadModuleFactory (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:42937)
    at a.load (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:42926)
    at b.project (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:43327)
    at b._tryNext (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:50090)
    at b._next (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:50084)
    at b.next (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:55977)
    at b._subscribe (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:54037)
    at b.a.subscribe (1499149250078.main.bundle.js?version=4562730455:formatted:55865)
```

this is how I am creating a bundle using gulp

```
gulp.task('bundle:app', function () {
     var builder = new Builder('./','./systemjs.config.js');
     builder.buildStatic('app/main.js', './dist/' + jsMainBundleName, {minify:true})        
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('App bundle error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Here is my system.config.js

```
(function (global) {

  var angular2ModalVer = '@2.0.0-beta.11';
  //var plugin = 'bootstrap'; // js-native / vex
  global.angular2ModalVer = angular2ModalVer;

  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      '@angular2-material/core': 'npm:@angular2-material/core/core.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/toolbar': 'npm:@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/sidenav': 'npm:@angular2-material/sidenav/sidenav.umd.js',
      'ng2-cookies': 'node_modules/ng2-cookies',
      'angular2-modal': 'node_modules/angular2-modal',
      'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': 'node_modules/angular2-modal/bundles/angular2-modal.bootstrap.umd.js',

      //shims
      'core-js-shim': 'npm:core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      'zone': 'npm:zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'reflect': 'npm:reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      'css': 'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-css/css.js',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      //'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }, 
    },

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-cookies': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-modal': {
        defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd'
      },
      'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap}': {
        defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'angular2-modal.bootstrap.umd'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { 
        defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js'
      }, 
    }
  });
})(this);
```

and this is how I am routing the modules.

```
{ path: 'profile', loadChildren:'./app/ui/dashboard/profile.module#ProfileRouteModule' }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add the system polyfill to your index.html page

e.g

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, node_modules folder is not there in build folder as it gets bundled named vendor.bundle.js. is there any other approach to achieve this ?. the above code works fine in develop environment but doesn't work when bundled together

Comment: The above was an example path, you can reference system.src.js from anywhere. Just ensure it has been added to the index.html page as a script

Comment: Even if I added the script will it be able to load the module ? because I am bundling my entire app into one single file. do u know how do I tackle that?

Comment: If you want multiple bundles don't use buildstatic, use the bundle function.